# How do you select multiple specific files?

Tags: finder

Say I've got 5 files, and I'd like to select just two of them. In Windows I would select file 1, then press <kbd>Control</kbd>, and then click file 5.

How could this be done in Mac Os X?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *<kbd>cmd</kbd> + click* if you are using a Mac keyboard or use the *Windows-key + click* if you are using a PC keyboard.

Answer (score 7):

You'll do the same thing by doing <kbd>Command</kbd>+Click.